# Query para obter todos os registos independentemente se existam ou não em outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou a realizar uma aplicação de uma loja em que os utilizadores possam deixar equipamentos para serem arranjados. Então fiz um php para procurar por nome esses utilizadores que já deixaram algum equipamento:

```
        $sql = mysqli_query("$conexao,
        SELECT u.contribuinte, u.nome, u.tlm
        FROM utilizador u, entrada e
        WHERE u.contribuinte = e.contribuinte
        AND u.nome LIKE  '%".$utilizador."%'
        ORDER BY e.data_entrada DESC 
        ");
```

No entanto na *query* acima eu consigo obter esses resultados, mas também queria obter os utilizadores independentemente se já deixaram algum equipamento ou não.
Ou seja quero que aparecam todos os utilizadores, tendo como prioridade os que já deixaram algum equipamento.

É a primeira vez que me aparece um caso desses, mas penso que seja possível realizar esta query. Agradeço desde já a ajuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o LEFT JOIN pra isso.

```
SELECT u.contribuinte, u.nome, u.tlm
FROM utilizador AS u
LEFT JOIN entrada AS e ON u.contribuinte = e.contribuinte
WHERE u.nome LIKE  '%".$utilizador."%'
ORDER BY e.data_entrada DESC
```

Comment: Obrigado Givanildo! nunca tinha usado nem tinha ouvido sobre essa keyword.

Comment: Blz @programmer2016. Quando puder, dê uma pesquisadinha sobre: tipos de Joins. Até +